# ADFS Claim rule to only allow access via a specific security group in AD

Tags: windows, adfs, box

I'm attempting to configure our internal ADFS Server (2K12 R2) to be able to access the cloud storage, "Box.com".  The traffic will pass through our DMZ ADFS Proxy server before it reaches the Box environment.  ADFS is currently configured and we are able to authenticate into the Box environment using out AD credentials, but I need to restrict it to just one security group whereas the current configuration permits all users.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: I apologize and thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Issuance Authorisation Rules" tab in the claims rules.

Delete the "All" rule.

Add Rule "Permit or Deny User Based on an Incoming Claim".